# multiline Jinja statement

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

app.py

```
@app.context_processor
def example():
    date=['2019','2020']
    return dict(ArrayDate=date)
```

template.html

```
<select>
{% for k in ArrayDate: %}
   <option value="{{ k }}" {% if {{ k }} == 2019 %} selected {% endif %} >{{ k }}</option>
{% endfor %} 
</select>
```

I have this error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

This code is the problem but i don't understand

```
{% if {{ k }} == 2019 %} selected {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

answer

```
<select>
{% for k in ArrayDate: %}
   <option value="{{ k }}" {% if k == '2019' %} selected {% endif %} >{{ k }}</option>
{% endfor %} 
</select>
```